# Call TableCellUpdated of JTable by MouseClick

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseclick-event

I used `fireTableCellUpdated` for `JTable`. `fireTableCellUpdated` call when I go through keyboard on the cell and updated cell  but when i click directly on cell and updated it then `fireTableCellUpdated` does not call. I don't know why is there any extra method I need to call?

Comment: You should not invoke `fireTableCellUpdated()` directly. This method is only invoked by the TableModel.

Comment: yes you are right,but when i go through keyboard i get tableFinishItem.getSelectedRow() = selectedrow but by mouseclick i get tableFinishItem.getSelectedRow() = -1.do not know why?

Comment: `do not know why?` - neither do we because we have no idea what you are doing. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I used following code to create Table :
  
        String col[] = {"S.N.", "Product", "Qty"};
        String data[][] = {{"", "", ""}};
     tableModelFinishItem = new DefaultTableModel(data, col) {
            @Override
            public void fireTableCellUpdated(int row, int column) {
                if (tableFinishItem.getSelectedRow() >= 0) {
                   System.out.println("Check For fireTableCellUpdated Call or Not");
                }
            }
        };

Comment: Thanks Camickr for helping me,I have solved problem.